# How can I understand the byte operation between Java and Nodejs

Tags: java, node.js

I have two code in Java and Nodejs to convert int to byte array:

```java
System.out.println((byte)254);
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString((byte)254));

-2
fffffffe
```

```js
> parseInt(Buffer.from([254]).toString('hex'), 16)
254
> Buffer.from([254]).toString('hex')
'fe'
```

compare above 2 codes, I have some questions:

- why Java prints 254 as `-2` in byte but nodejs prints it as `254`?
- Java adds 6 `f` in the prefix of hex string, but node only prints `fe`.
- Are these two byte same in the two lanugages?

Comment: I don't know nodejs but your code is different in the two isn't it? In the Java, you cast to ```byte``` . Try it without the cast

Comment: using byte is what I want. I am converting int to byte in the two languages but it gives me different output

Comment: ```byte``` is a signed type in Java. The maximum positive value is 127. Depending on what you're doing, you probably don't need to worry

Comment: Java's byte is an 8-bit signed value. 254 is 0xfe which is -2 in an 8-bit signed, two's complement value. If you widen this (byte to int) then sign extension happens and 0xfe becomes 0xfffffffe.